# How to distinguishing between Task Scheduler 1.0 and Task Scheduler 2.0?

Tags: c#, task, scheduler, scheduled-tasks

I have an C# application that uses Task Scheduler 1.0 (.job files).
I need to extend the application to support Task Scheduler 2.0 (xml).

I need some code, that is able to tell me what kind of T.S. is running on the current customer machine. Is it possible?

Comment: A workaround could be to ask if the mashine is a Vista, Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7, and then use Task Scheduler 2.0. But i don't think it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task Scheduler 2.0 introduces ITaskService interface and scripting support. So you can try if COM Object for this class exists or not. For example,

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Schedule.Service");
if (null != t) 
{
   // we definitely have 2.0 version
}
else
{
  // 1.0 version
}
```

*Disclaimer: untested code. I have picked up prog id from MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446862(v=VS.85).aspx*

Answer (score 0):

You could poke around the various versions of schedsvc.dll (which is the file that actually hosts the task scheduler code), but the workaround you mention about determining the machine's OS version and then deciding which version of the task scheduler to use is the right one.  From the doc at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446802(VS.85).aspx,

> Where Task Scheduler is Installed
>
> The Task Scheduler is automatically
>   installed with several Microsoft
>   operating systems.
>
> Task Scheduler 1.0 is installed with
>   the Windows Server 2003, Windows XP,
>   and Windows 2000 operating systems.
>
> Task Scheduler 2.0 is installed with
>   Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.